# Can't figure out how to send Motor Values over Bluetooth, Arduino Bluetooth-controller robot

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I was trying to make an Arduino Robot that is Bluetooth controlled but I've some problems!

I can't figure out how to parse strings in Arduino like c++/java/python!
I tried this, If the first letter is L, set the next value to left motor, same for R

but for example "L255" is received as L - 2 - 5 - 5 and it sets L to 2 and ignores 5 - 5.

Any ideas on what I should do?

EDIT: Thought of something else, Sending L or R will toggle the motors! but that's just terrible, it'll be my last option

Update: This is how it works now:
L(0-5) means Left motor speed 5 * 51, 6-9 are backwards! its go backwards at (L(6-9) -5 * 51)

Comment: Either collect characters until you have a full string (probably terminated with a newline) or else create a `state machine` which interprets characters one at a time as they are received, for example first deciding on a mode based on a letter, then doing a multiply-and-add on digits to create a value, and executing on the newline.

Comment: :O Good idea! I'll try that tomorrow :) thanks! But I just realized, I also don't need my speed to be so accurate, It can be from 0-9! but anyway that's also good for future stuff and way better than inaccurate speed :)

Comment: I'm starting to think my lpc1678 is better for this :) but its too hard to work with :S my board is so huge!

Comment: Further to Chris Stratton's comment, you can read about using [state machines](http://www.gammon.com.au/serial) for processing serial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A state machine is the right way to go if you are sending multibyte commands.

However do you need to send 4 bytes for every turn? Do you need accuracy to one degree? Are you going to make regular turns of greater than 60 degrees?  If not I would consider encoding the dAta into a single byte.  You will reduce the radio bandwidth by 3/4, it will improve the responsiveness of. Your software and it will remove the need to have a handler for incomplete messages.

Of course there are probably other requirements that I don't know that will stop you doing this, but in case you haven't thought of it.

Comment: For my RC Car its enough! (0-9 speed) but I would love to know about it just for other projects :) But chris and Nick told me how to do so! Thanks :)